# Time Complexity single loop vs multiple sequential loops

Tags: algorithm, performance, loops, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Today, me and my colleague had a small argument about one particular code snippet. The code looks something like this. At least, this is what he imagined it to be.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // Some operations here
}

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) { // m is always small
    // Some more operations here
}
```

He wanted me to remove the second loop, since it would cause performance issues.

However, I was sure that since I don't have any nested loops here, the complexity will always be **O(n)**, no matter how many sequential loops I put (only 2 we had).

His argument was that if `n` is 1,000,000 and the loop takes 5 seconds, my code will take 10 seconds, since it has 2 for loops. I was confused after this statement.

What I remember from my DSA lessons is that we ignore such constants while calculating Big Oh.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's not the number of loops that count, but the number of *operations*, i.e. actual work done. Having one additional loop would only add a small amount of overhead (checking and incrementing the index + jumps), but may actually be necessary in some cases.

Comment: By now I know that two separate code snippets having only one and two for loops respectively doing same operations for same number of iterations will not have same running time. Code with two loops will take longer to run than code with one loop. I am still not sure if the time difference would actually be double. Code with two loops will take twice as much time as code with one loop?

Comment: No, you seem to be confused about what actually uses up the time in this code. If your operations are *very very* simple, e.g. incrementing a number, then the overhead of an extra loop will be significant. If on the other hand you are doing some reasonably complex operation, then the overhead would be negligible. Overall though the time complexity will *always* be O(n), so I don't think the `asymptotic-complexity` tag is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,
the complexity theory may help to compare two distinct methods of calculation in `[?TIME][?SPACE]`,
**but**

### Do not use `[PTIME]` complexity as an argument for a poor efficiency

---

**Fact #1:** **`O( f(N) )`** is relevant for comparing complexities, in areas near `N ~ INFTY`, so the process principal limits are being possible to be compared "there"

**Fact #2:** Given `N ~ { 10k | 10M | 10G }`, none of such cases meets the above cited condition

**Fact #3:** If the process ( algorithm ) allows the loops to get merged without any side-effects ( on resources / blocking / etc ) into a single pass, the single-loop processing may always benefit from the reduced looping overheads.

---

### A micro benchmark will decide, not the `O( f( N ) )` for `N ~ INFTY`

as many additional effects get stronger influence - better or poor cache-line alignment and the amount of possible L1/L2/L3-cache re-uses, smart harnessing of more / less CPU-registers - all of which is driven by possible compiler-optimisations and may further increase code-execution speeds for small **`N`**-s, beyond any expectations from above.

So,
do perform several scaling-dependent microbenchmarking, before resorting to argue about limits of `O( f( N ) )`

**Always do.**

Answer (score 1):

You may be confusing time complexity and performance. These are two different (but related) things.

Time complexity deals with comparing the rate of growth of algorithms and ignores constant factors and messy real-world conditions. These simplifications make it a valuable theoretical framework for reasoning about algorithm scalability.

Performance is how fast code runs on an actual computer. Unlike in Big O-land, constant factors exist and often play a dominant role in determining execution time. Your coworker is reasonable to acknowledge this. It's easy to forget that O(1000000n) is the same as O(n) in Big O-land, but to an actual computer, the constant factor is a very real thing.

The bird's-eye view that Big O provides is still valuable; it can help determine if your coworker is getting lost in the details and pursuing a micro-optimization.

Furthermore, your coworker considers simple instruction counting as a step towards comparing actual performance of these loop arrangements, but this is still a major simplification. Consider cache characteristics; out-of-order execution potential; friendliness to prefetching, loop unrolling, vectorization, branch prediction, register allocation and other compiler optimizations; garbage collection/allocation overhead and heap vs stack memory accesses as just a few of the factors that can make enormous differences in execution time beyond including simple operations in the analysis.

For example, if your code is something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    foo(arr[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    bar(arr[i]);
}
```

and `n` is large enough that `arr` doesn't fit neatly in the cache (perhaps elements of `arr` are themselves large, heap-allocated objects), you may find that the second loop has a dramatically harmful effect due to having to bring evicted blocks back into the cache all over again. Rewriting it as

```
for (int i = 0, end = max(n, m); i < end; i++) {
    if (i < n) {
        foo(arr[i]);
    }

    if (i < m) {
        bar(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

*may* have a disproportionate efficiency increase because blocks from `arr` are brought into the cache once. The `if` statements might seem to add overhead, but branch prediction may make the impact negligible, avoiding pipeline flushes.

Conversely, if `arr` fits in the cache, the second loop's performance impact may be negligible (particularly if `m` is bounded and, better still, small).

Yet again, what is happening in `foo` and `bar` could be a critical factor. There simply isn't enough information here to tell which is likely to run faster by looking at these snippets, simple as they are, and the same applies to the snippets in the question.

In some cases, the compiler may have enough information to generate the same code for both of these examples.

Ultimately, the only hope to settle debates like this is to write an accurate benchmark (not necessarily an easy task) that measures the code under its normal working conditions (not always possible) and evaluate the outcome against other constraints and metrics you may have for the app (time, budget, maintainability, customer needs, energy efficiency, etc...).

If the app meets its goals or business needs either way it may be premature to debate performance. Profiling is a great way to determine if the code under discussion is even a problem. See Eric Lippert's [Which is Faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) which makes a strong case for (usually) not worrying about these sort of things.

This is a benefit of Big O--if two pieces of code only differ by a small constant factor, there's a decent chance it's not worth worrying about until it proves to be worth attention through profiling.

Answer (score 0):

In asymptotic notation, your code has time complexity O(n + n) = O(2n) =

> O(n)

---

*Side note:*
If the first loop takes `n` iterations and the second loop `m`, then the time complexity would be O(n + m).

---

PS: I assume that the bodies of your for loops is not heavy enough to affect the overall complexity, as you mentioned too.

Comment: With similar logic, if my first loop takes 'n' iterations and second loop also takes 'n' iterations, time complexitty would be O(n+n)? (from sidenote). Which is same as O(2n), which again is equal to O(n)?

Comment: Also, will my time reduce to half if I remove 1 of the loops? Look at the question once more, if it takes 5 sec with one loop, will it take 10 seconds with two loops?

Comment: Right @SahilPatel, answer updated! It's not as simle as that Sahil. It depends...