# Time complexity of nested for loops vs N for loops

Tags: time-complexity

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        /*Something in O(1)*/
```

```
for i in range(n):
    /*Something in O(1)*/
for i in range(n):
    /*Something in O(1)*/
.
.
.
.
n times
```

I know that the time complexity of the first code will be O(n^2). But what will be the time complexity of the second code? Is the second just linear or something? if the second code is O(n^2), then I think I might have a problem as I have seen thousands of simple for loops in a code and I considered the code then still O(n). And if this is the case, I think the time complexity big O notation should also consider the constants as the constants can change the code from linear to quadratic.

Comment: Second is O(n+n) = O(n) = linear. First is O(n * n) = O(n^2) = quadratic. From this, you can see the pattern is that nested is multiplicative (for every outer, you're doing the inner loop) and sequential/non-nested is additive, take the larger of the two as dominant if they're different. Even if you have 20 million sequential loops, it's still O(20000000n) = O(n) (some people find this hard to accept, but time complexity doesn't care about constants).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time Complexity single loop vs multiple sequential loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171238/time-complexity-single-loop-vs-multiple-sequential-loops)

Comment: BTW, quadratic code is not always slower than linear code due to the constant factor and a specific value of `n`. Time complexity just says "there exists some value of `n` where the quadratic code will be slower", but that `n` may be massive.